# Workflow rule that will send an email to some user

Tags: formula, workflow, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I have this task - send an email alert 3 weeks before Next_Internal_Review_Date__c(field) if the date is not equal to 31/01 or 30/09 to me. For this I have created workflow rule with time dependant email alert action, Here is my formula for it:

```
OR(
AND(MONTH( Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 9,
DAY(Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 30),
AND(MONTH( Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 1,
DAY(Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 31))
```

but for some reason when I tested workflow rule is not sending me any email (I checked email deliverability and deliverability settings), and I also think that my formula is not correct and I need add something to make it work properly but for now I am stuck and looking for help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with formula, finally have found solution on this. Formula seems weird and can be adjusted but it works  :)

```
NOT(
OR(
AND(
AND(MONTH( Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 9,
DAY(Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 30),
AND(MONTH( Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) = 1,
DAY(Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) = 31)),
AND(
AND(MONTH( Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) = 9,
DAY(Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) = 30),
AND(MONTH( Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 1,
DAY(Next_Internal_Review_Date__c ) <> 31))))
```